# For an NFA with langauge: {w ∈ {0, 1}*: the length of w is odd but not a multiple of three}. How many states are required?

Tags: theory

For an NFA with language: {w ∈ {0, 1}*: the length of w is odd but not a multiple of three}. How many states are required?

This is the work I have come up with so far:
q0: non-accepting state - because of even length
q1: accepting state - because odd length and not multiple of 3
q2: non-accepting state - because even length
q3: non-accepting state - because multiple of 3
So, then I suspect that the transitions would be
q0 to q1 on 0,1
q1 to q2 on 0,1
q2 to q3 on 0,1

But I'm not sure where q3 loops to?
I would appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Why don't you build two automata, one for "odd length" and the other for "not a multiple of 3", and then product them?

Comment: What is "$\{0, 1\}?$"  ?

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi Thank you that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Steven Sorry about that! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: If n is the length of the input then you want n modulo 6 = 1 or 5. 6 states for the six values of n modulo 6, of which two are accepting.